# saving to a string from a pipe

Tags: c, scanf, popen

I have code here that runs `/bin/ls -l` and then prints out the output to the terminal, what I want to do here is save that output into a string for later use. I'm not sure how to go about doing this but from my guess it would look something like this

```
int main (){
    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    char path[100];
    char *s;
    fp = popen("/bin/ls -l", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("fp error");
    }
    while(fgets(path,100,fp)!= NULL){
        printf("%s\n", path );
        scanf(path, s);
    }
    status = pclose(fp);
    if (status==-1){
        printf("pclose error");
    }else{
        printf("else on pclose\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The while loop prints out my directory result no problem but I run into a segmentation fault : 11 at the end of it. What would be the correct way of approaching this problem?

Comment: What do you expect this to do? `scanf(path, s);`

Comment: I was hoping it would send the text in path into the string s, but I realize that that wouldn't work.

Comment: You might be thinking of `sscanf`. But there are better options -- like `strncpy`. Also `s` is uninitialized -- it doesn't point to any allocated memory. You'll have to deal with the allocations and reallocations.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you trying to save **all** of the output from `ls` for later use, either as an array of strings (one per line) or a single, multi-line string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with `while(fgets(path,100,fp)!= NULL){` already stores the first `99`characters read from the pipe in `path`. There is no need to `scanf` anything else.

`100` is a horribly insufficient *magic number* to include in your code for the maximum path length. Better to use `PATH_MAX` defined in `limits.h`. (generally `4096`, but is implementation defined). Which brings up another point, don't use *magic numbers* in your code, if you need a constant the system doesn't provide, then `#define` one, or use a global `enum` to define it.

When reading with `fgets`, you must check for, and remove (or otherwise account for) the `'\n'` that will be included in the buffer filled by `fgets` (and POSIX `getline`). That also provides validation that you did in fact read a complete line of data. Otherwise, if the length of the line read is `PATH_MAX - 1` and there was no `'\n'` at the end, the line was too long for the buffer and character for that line remain unread in your input stream. A simple call to `strlen (path)` and then checks with `if/else if` statements provide the validation and allow you to overwrite the trailing `'\n'` with a *nul-terminating* character.

To handle the problem of "How many files to I need to provide for?", you can simply use a *pointer-to-pointer-to-char* and dynamically allocate pointers to each line and `realloc` additional pointers as required. You assign the address of each block of memory you allocate to store each line, to the individual pointers you allocate. Keep a count of the lines (for the pointer count) and `realloc` more pointers when you reach your limit (this works for reading from text files the same way) Don't forget to free the memory you allocate when you are done with it.

Putting all the pieces together, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define NFILES 16

int main (){

    size_t i, n = 0,            /* number of files in listing    */
        nfiles = NFILES;        /* number of allocated pointers  */
    char path[PATH_MAX] = "",   /* buffer (PATH_MAX in limits.h) */
        **files = NULL;         /* pointer to pointer to file    */
    FILE *fp = popen("/bin/ls -l", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {           /* validate pipe open for reading */
        perror ("popen");
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate/validate initial number of pointers */
    if (!(files = malloc (nfiles * sizeof *files))) {
        perror ("malloc - files");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (path, PATH_MAX, fp)) {    /* read each line */

        size_t len = strlen (path);         /* get length     */
        if (len && path[len - 1] == '\n')   /* validate '\n'  */
            path[--len] = 0;                /* trim '\n'      */
        else if (len + 1 == PATH_MAX) {     /* check path too long */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: path too long.\n");
            /* handle remaining chars in fp */
        }

        /* allocate/validate storage for line */
        if (!(files[n] = malloc (len + 1))) {
            perror ("malloc - files[n]");
            break;
        }

        strcpy (files[n++], path);          /* copy path */

        if (n == nfiles) {  /* realloc pointers as required */
            void *tmp = realloc (files, nfiles * 2 * sizeof *files);
            if (!tmp) {
                perror ("realloc");
                break;
            }
            files = tmp;
            nfiles *= 2;        /* increment current allocation */
        }
    }


    if (pclose (fp) == -1)      /* validate close */
        perror ("pclose");

    /* print and free the allocated strings */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("%s\n", files[i]);    
        free (files[i]);        /* free individual file storage */
    }
    free (files);               /* free pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/popen_ls_files > dat/filelist.txt

$ wc -l dat/filelist.txt
1768 dat/filelist.txt

$ cat dat/filelist.txt
total 9332
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     376 Sep 23  2014 3darrayaddr.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     466 Sep 30 20:13 3darrayalloc.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     802 Jan 25 02:55 3darrayfill.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     192 Jun 27  2015 BoggleData.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    3565 Jun 26  2014 DoubleLinkedList-old.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    3699 Jun 26  2014 DoubleLinkedList.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    3041 Jun 26  2014 DoubleLinkedList.diff
<snip>
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    4946 May  7  2015 workers.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     206 Jul 11  2017 wshadow.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    1283 May 18  2015 wsininput.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    5519 Oct 13  2015 xpathfname.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     785 Sep 30 02:49 xrealloc2_macro.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    2090 Sep  6 02:29 xrealloc_tst.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    1527 Sep  6 03:22 xrealloc_tst_str.c
-rwxr-xr--  1 david david     153 Aug  5  2014 xsplit.sh
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/popen_ls_files > /dev/null
==7453== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7453== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7453== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7453== Command: ./bin/popen_ls_files
==7453==
==7453==
==7453== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7453==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7453==   total heap usage: 1,777 allocs, 1,777 frees, 148,929 bytes allocated
==7453==
==7453== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7453==
==7453== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7453== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Nice and clean answer with good explanations and clear demonstration how to use `realloc`!

Comment: @sg7, that's pretty much the standard "meat & potatoes" way of doing it. If you want to set your new pointers to zero after `realloc`, then after assigning `file = tmp;`, you can do `memset (files + nfiles, 0, nfiles * sizeof *files);` before you `nfiles *= 2;`. (that will allow you to iterate over filled pointers, e.g. `i = 0; while (files[i]) { do stuff; i++; }`)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to save directories into the array of strings. In this case array of `s[]` keeps pointers to all your entries. Every read entry would get allocated memory for the entry and the string terminator `\0`.

The starting program may look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NR_OF_ENTRIES 10000
#define PATH_LEN    256

int main (){
    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    char path[PATH_LEN];
    char *s[MAX_NR_OF_ENTRIES]; 
    int i,j = 0;

    fp = popen("/bin/ls -l", "r");

    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("fp error\n");
    }

    while(fgets(path,PATH_LEN,fp) != NULL){

        printf("%s\n", path );

        s[i] = malloc(strlen(path)+1);
        strcpy(s[i],path);
        i++;

        if(i>=MAX_NR_OF_ENTRIES) 
        {
            printf("MAX_NR_OF_ENTRIES reached!\n");     
            break;
        }
    }


    status = pclose(fp);
    if (status==-1){
        printf("pclose error");
    }else{
        printf("pclose was fine!\n");
    }

    // Print and free the allocated strings
    for(j=0; j< i; j++){
        printf("%s\n", s[j] );    
        free (s[j]);        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That works, but we put 10,000 pointers on the stack. But, as suggested by David C. Rankin, we could allocate array of arrays `s` dynamically as well. Starting working program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NR_OF_ENTRIES 10
#define PATH_LEN    256

int main (){
    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    char path[PATH_LEN];

    int i,j = 0;

    size_t nr_of_elements = MAX_NR_OF_ENTRIES;

    char **old_arr;
    char **new_arr;

    char **s = calloc(nr_of_elements, sizeof(char*));

    fp = popen("/bin/ls -l", "r");

    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("fp error\n");
    }

    while(fgets(path,PATH_LEN,fp) != NULL){

        printf("%s\n", path );

        char *str = malloc(strlen(path)+1);
        strcpy(str, path);
        s[i] = str;

        i++;

        if(i>=nr_of_elements ) 
        {
            printf("resizing\n");     
            size_t old_size = nr_of_elements; 
            nr_of_elements = 4*nr_of_elements; // increase size for `s` 4 times (you can invent something else here)
            old_arr = s; 

            // allocating a bigger copy of the array s, copy it inside, and redefine the pointer:

            new_arr = calloc(nr_of_elements, sizeof(char*));

            if (!new_arr) 
             {
                 perror("new calloc failed");
                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
             }

            memcpy (new_arr, old_arr, sizeof(char*)*old_size);   // notice the use of `old_size` 

            free (old_arr);
            s = new_arr;
         }
    }


    status = pclose(fp);
    if (status==-1){
        printf("pclose error");
    }else{
        printf("pclose was fine!\n");
    }

    // Print and free the allocated strings
    for(j=0; j< i; j++){
        printf("%s\n", s[j] );    
        free (s[j]);        
    }

    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works, but if you are going to put `10,000` pointers on the stack, you might as well go ahead allocate the pointers dynamically as well. Otherwise you are way over allocated for a directory with 4-files in it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You are absolutely right! I added one of the solutions to use that approach in the second version of the program.

Comment: That is a better approach, somewhat non-standard, but better nonetheless. Take a look at the other answer and see if you can trim down the number of declared pointer-to-pointer-to-char you are using. It's not a right or wrong thing, more an issue of refinement. (less use of `memcpy`, where `realloc` will do.) If you want to zero the new pointers, you can always call `memset` `:)`

Comment: How does `memcpy (new_arr, old_arr, sizeof(char*)*nr_of_elements);` work out after you have already done `nr_of_elements = 4*nr_of_elements;`? Doesn't that read beyond the bounds of `old_arr = s;` (`valgrind` is your friend here)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you again! Yes, that was overreach!

Comment: Much better -- your only nagging nit is your `printf("%s\n", s[j] );` will print everything *double-spaced* due to the trailing `'\n'` included in each of your `s[j]` from `fgets`. Look at the test for `'\n'` and then trim the `'\n'` by setting `path[len - 1] = 0` (or to `'\0'` -- same difference). Or use `--len` to end up with the updated length after you trim `:)` (that's why you want to store `size_t len = strlen (path);`...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin True! `\n` is not needed in the `printf`. I did not trim `path` also. I was not sure what the AFC's intentions are regarding the trailing `\n` but quite likely he does not need it.

Comment: As long as you account for the `'\n'` in some manner you are good, but note, you generally don't want to store strings in your code with `'\n'`'s dangling off the end, That becomes horribly problematic when you call `strcmp` looking for a specific line. Best to trim them off as they are read. Much more efficient than having to remember to do `strncmp (s[j], "some compare", strlen (s[j]) - 1);` and remembering "Now which have newlines and which don't?"